# limit of a sequence relative to a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, limits, normed-spaces

Assume we have some vector space $ V$ and a norm $ ||•|| $.

If I hve a sequence $ v_n $  that converge to a vector relative to the norm, that is, $ lim ||v_{n}-v || =0 $.

How can I show that $lim ||v_{n}||=||v|| $?

I tried to use the squeeze theorem and wrote:

$ ||v_n||=||v_n -v+v|| \leq ||v_n-v|| + ||v || $

This gives me the the limit is smaller or equals to ||v||.

What can I do in order to show the other direction?

Comment: Use the same trick: $\|v\| = \|v - v_n + v_n\| \leq \|v - v_n\| + \|v\|$

Comment: Equivalently, the "reverse triangle inequality" tells you that
$$
\|v_n - v\| \geq |\,\|v_n\| - \|v\|\,| 
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann I need something smaller than $ ||v_n|| $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $\|v_n\| \leq \|v_n-v\|+\|v\|$ one has $\|v_n\|-\|v\| \leq \|v_n-v\|$, and from $$ \qquad \|v\| = \|\!-\!v\| = \|(v_n-v)-v_n\| \leq \|v_n-v\|+\|v_n\|$$ one has $-\|v_n-v\| \leq \|v_n\|-\|v\|$. Thus $$-\|v_n-v\| \leq \|v_n\|-\|v\| \leq \|v_n-v\|$$ and then taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we conclude that $\lim_n (\|v_n\|-\|v\|) = 0$.

Comment: That's great. Thanks!